# Set a keyboard shortcut to switch between headset and external speakers (Win XP)

Tags: windows-xp, speakers, headphones

I have both external speakers (plugged into the 1/8" jack on the back of the PC) and headphones (in 1/8" jack on the front of the PC).  My computer automatically mutes the speakers when I plug in the headphones and unmutes it when I remove the headphones.  I'd like a way to leave the headphones plugged in, and control through which jack sound is sent via a keyboard shortcut (or taskbar icon if need be).  I.e. I could hit CTRL-SHIFT-M (or whatever) to swap between speakers and headphones.

I'm using Win XP on Dell Optiplex hardware.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by purchasing a cheap [headphone splitter](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=headphone+splitter)

[image]

I plugged that into the back of my computer putting my speakers into one and my headphones into the other.

Comment: But then both are always on, right?  What about when you only want the headphones?  (My speakers are pretty low-tech, don't have a separate power button or volume control)

Comment: Not to mention vice-versa... I often wear my headphones throughout the day for phone calls (via skype) but prefer listening to ambient music when I'm not on a call.  I'd prefer not to have to take off the headphones to silence them.

Comment: @Benj - My speakers have a separate volume/power control so that's not a problem for me, and the headphones are always on (not on *me* but they always play music) doesn't bother me as I can't here them over the speakers.